# core-pages not working in polymer project

Tags: polymer

Instead of rendering the second section, like it should, it just renders all of them. Anyone know why? The platform is not letting me post the question unless I write some more stuff, so here it is. Stuff written by me. I would just like to know about the core-pages issue.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
    </head>
        <body unresolved> 
            <core-pages selected="1">
                <section>
                    <h1>hola</h1>
                    <p>this is the first section</p>
                </section> 
                <section>
                    <h1>hello</h1>
                    <p>this is the second section</p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h1>ciao</h1>
                    <p>third</p>
                </section>
            </core-pages>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `core-pages` are for old Polymer 0.5. Maybe you should use [`iron-pages`](https://github.com/polymerelements/iron-pages) instead?

Comment: Thank you for that. <iron-pages> don't show anything. Nothing at all. I'm doing the simple example with the three <div>s and the selected="0" attribute. "Falling Down" with Michael Douglas.

Comment: I got it to work by removing all the imports except for <iron-pages>. Looks like some weird interaction between components..

Comment: so which version of polymer are you using?